# Collada material is not repeated

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I have a collada model (.dae) and I load it in Three js. An object's material should look like this:
 [image]

but it looks like this:
[image]

The color is not problem, I can adjust the light added to the `THREE.Scene`, but it looks like the image used for material is not repeating.

Comment: Looks like the VertexUV coordinates are not correct, please check if that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a non-power-of-two problem. Make sure your texture file has power of two sides (in pixels).